# PHP code in wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress

What is wrong with my code in index.php? or maybe not in my code? I'm creating a new theme from scratch. Direction of files is correct. Theme is activated. But text is not showing up.

```
   <?php

get_header();

if(have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<h2>hello</h2>
  <?php the_content(); ?>

  <?php endwhile;

  else :
    echo '<p>No content found</p>'

endif;

get_footer();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are missing a semicolon.** `echo '<p>No content found</p>'` should be `echo '<p>No content found</p>';`, hence why you are getting the [white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death). So the full code, looks like so:

```
<?php

get_header();

if( have_posts() ):
  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <h2>hello</h2>
  <?php the_content(); ?>

  <?php endwhile;

else:
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;

get_footer();

?>
```

If you are using WordPress 4+ and in development, you should edit your **wp-config.php** file in the project root. Set the constant `WP_DEBUG` on line 80 to true to look like this:

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

This will show the syntax errors in your code instead of a white blank screen...and of course change it back to false when you ship the production version.